# squid - logfile based on source

Tags: linux, proxy, logging, squid, exclude

According to some googled documents, I am trying to set up per-host logfile to exclude some requests from access log, but to keep these requests in different logfile. My related config in squid.conf:

```
acl scanner src 10.0.1.202
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/scanner.log squid scanner
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log squid !scanner
```

And the problem is - some requests from 10.0.1.2020 ends in access.log (TAG_NONE )and some ends in scanner.log (TCP_DENIED), I have no clue what is wrong with my configuration. OS RHEL 7.8, squid 3.5.20